# Print file names and character count of each file - Looping

Tags: bash, for-loop, scripting

I am looking to write a for loop which prints the names of all files and directories inside my current working directory along with the number of characters each file and directory name possess. I currently have the below, it doesn't work as I intend, any suggestions to the below?

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/c/Users/johndoe/unix/*

for i in $FILES
do
    echo "$FILES has" | wc -c
done;
```

Comment: Why does it now work as intended?

Comment: When I run this script it doesn't list the file names, it lists numbers only. I would like it to list say:                                                                                                  File1 has 10                                                                                                         File2 has 18                                                                                                           File3 Has 28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array

```
Files=(/c/Users/johndoe/unix/*)
for i in "${Files[@]}"
do
        wc -c "$i"
done
```

Also you should quote your variables, and it's advised not to use UPPERCASE variable names as they can conflict with environment variables.

If you aren't reusing the filename list you could also just simply do

```
wc -c /c/Users/johndoe/unix/*
```

And if you wanted to recursively check dirs you could use find

```
find /c/Users/johndoe/unix/ -type f -exec wc -c {} \;
```

Comment: `wc -c` imho. He needs count characters, not lines.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no whitespace in file/dir names, a simple `find` can count the characters inside the filenames it finds.

```
$ find /c/Users/johndoe/unix/ -type f -exec wc -c {} \;
7751  /c/Users/johndoe/unix/a.txt
890 /c/Users/johndoe/unix/b.txt
```

Though, I am not entirely clear, whether you want the characters the file contains, or just the character in the filename. Like, `a.txt` has `5` characters.

For this, you have to do a little more:

```
$ find /c/Users/johndoe/unix/ -exec basename {} \;| xargs -I {} sh -c 'p={};echo "${p} ${#p}"'
a.txt 5
ez.txt 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILES in /c/Users/johndoe/unix/*
do
    [ -f "${FILES}" ] && echo "$FILES" has $(wc -c "${FILES}" | awk '{print $1}')
done
```

Try it. Script checks if `"${FILES}"` is file. If it is, counting characters and print in output.

My output (`$FILES` modified in my case):

```
nginx.py has 1245
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC ~]$ wc -c nginx.py 
1245 nginx.py
```

Comment: Thank you, what is the awk at the end doing?

Comment: @user3296793 prints only first column (number of chars, filename you print with `echo`.

Comment: Did you test this, it doesn't seem like it would work at all? You are using `-f` against the entire expanded `$FILES` variable which would always return false unless there was only one file.

Comment: Ignoring case issues, `FILE` would be a better name than `FILES`; the name is never bound to more than one file name at a time.

Comment: @chepner agree, just decided to safe OP's variable names.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is super late. but i found it :)

```
~$ for i in $( find * ); do echo -n "$i has " ; echo -n $i | wc -c ; done
2021-06-28-205544.term has 22
backup.sh has 9
file1.txt has 9
welcome.sh has 10
```

but i have to use 2 `echo` in this